# Set Terminal Environment for a command launched into a Swift program

Tags: swift, macos, command, locale, cat

I give an example of two different behaviors.

- When I execute in Terminal:

  ```
  $cat -v /private/tmp/input.txt > /private/tmp/output.txt
  ```

  I have this result:

  ```
  $file -I /private/tmp/output.txt

  /private/tmp/output.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
  ```

  The result iso-8859-1 is great for me.
- And when I run this Swift program:

  ```
  func exec(_ path: String, _ args: String...) -> Int32 {
  let task = Process()
  task.launchPath = path
  task.arguments = args
  task.launch()
  task.waitUntilExit()
  return task.terminationStatus
  }
  exec("/bin/sh", "-c", "cat -v /tmp/input.txt > /tmp/output.txt")
  ```

  I have this result:

  ```
  $file -I /private/tmp/output.txt
  /private/tmp/output.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
  ```

  us-ascii is not what I want here.

---

I would like my program have the iso-8849-1 result file (for my example of course).
I found how to change the result in the Terminal. 
I retrieve 'us-ascii' if I unchecked "Set locale environment variables on startup" in the Preferences of the Terminal. So I think that my program don't use these variables. Am I wrong?

If not, what I would like to know is:
how to set the user locale environment variables into my program?

And I don't want to apply a constant environment, but I would like that 'cat' command uses the environment from the user who starts my program.

Comment: Do you run the Swift program from within Xcode, or by executing it on the command line?

Comment: Within Xcode in Product Menu, Run. 
And also after Product Menu, Archive, I put in Applications folder and launch it.